# How to create new table cells with loop?

Tags: javascript, tablecell

How do I create new table cells with a loop that checks how many rows there are and adds a new table cell at the end of each row?

Example html:

```
 <table id ="my_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                            <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                            <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                            <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                            <th>lorem ipsum</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                            <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                        </tr>
```

This is how I create one td:

```
function my_test() {
    var my_tbody = document.getElementById('my_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows[0];
    var my_td = document.createElement('td');
    my_td.innerHTML = 'test';    
    my_table.appendChild(my_td);
}
```

Here's how I was thinking it would work with a for-statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < my_table.length; i++) {
...and then the code above in here.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to accomplish what you're looking for. I call Array's `slice()` on the `NodeList` returned from `querySelectorAll` so I can use Array's functions on it.

```js
var tbody = document.getElementById('my_table').querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
  rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbody);

rows.forEach(function(row) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.textContent = 'New node';
  row.appendChild(td);
});
```

```html
<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="3" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That did it. It's more complex than I imagined.